# Filter several ListViews via SearchView

Tags: android, android-listview, filter

I have implemented precisely ONE ListView (with header attached) filtering according to SearchView input. Now I'm planning to make SearchView filter several ListViews and I wonder how to do it. I'm stuck and have no ideas. The main principle of filtering is such: 
We have several categories(i.e. accomodation, places of interest), which serve as headers (basically, the picture of category) displayed with ListViews attached for each of the category. When user enters the search query, the application needs to have all the ListViews filtered at once. The structure of the window is this:

->Header of the current category

ListView #1

When user enters input, all the available categories are displayed and the filter is applied for them:

->Header of the current category

Filtered ListView #1

->Header #2

Filtered ListView #2

...

->Header #8

Filtered ListView #8

I seek for the clearest/most genious way for performing this. Worth to mention, we know the exact count of categories.

I'm posting my code snippets(ONE ListView (with header attached) filtering according to SearchView input). Moreover, I print the message if search returns no results so that the user can contact us, if he desires.
list_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line_left1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/small_icon"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/pavalgyk" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/line_left2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.45"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

alllists.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@drawable/card"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/search_window_text"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="normal"
            android:autoLink="email"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

AllLists.java

```
public class AllLists extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
    private Context context = null;
    private int position = 0;
    private String location;
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private List<Item> tmp_items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private String tmp_s = "";
    private static Locale myLocale;
    private EasyTracker easyTracker = null;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alllists, container, false);
        View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.small_icon);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        setLanguage();
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        position = bundle.getInt("position");
        location = bundle.getString("location");
        image.setImageDrawable(navMenuIcons.getDrawable(position));
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(context);
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        items = db.getAllItems(location);
        tmp_items = db.getAllItems(location);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, items);
        listView.addHeaderView(header, "", false);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int list_position, long id) {
                easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("List",
                        location, adapter.getItems().get(list_position - 1).getName(), null).build());
                if (location.equals("accommodation") || location.equals("eat") || location.equals("events")
                        || location.equals("entertainment") || location.equals("places") || location.equals("cinema")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, ItemScreen.class);
                    i.putExtra("position", list_position - 1);
                    i.putExtra("location", location);
                    i.putExtra("name", adapter.getItems().get(list_position - 1).getRealName());
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (location.equals("taxi")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + adapter.getItems().get(list_position - 1).getType()));
                    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
                    List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
                    if (infos.size() > 0)
                        startActivity(intent);
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.cant_handle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("Search",
                        "search", s, null).build());
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, tmp_items);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                if (tmp_s.length() > s.length()) {
                    adapter.getFilter(tmp_items, true).filter(s, new Filter.FilterListener() {
                        public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                            if (count == 0)
                                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            else
                                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    adapter.getFilter(tmp_items, false).filter(s, new Filter.FilterListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                            if (count == 0)
                                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            else
                                relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    });
                }
                tmp_s = s;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        mSearchView.setQuery("", false);
    }
}
```

CustomListAdapted.java

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<Item> items;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        Item i = items.get(position);

        image.setImageUrl(i.getIcon(), imageLoader);
        if(items.get(0).getName().contains("taksi"))
            image.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.telefonas);
        else
            image.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.be_fono);
        name.setText(i.getRealName());
        type.setText(i.getType());
        return convertView;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems(){
        return items;
    }

    public Filter getFilter(final List<Item> all_items, final boolean deleted) {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
                    results.values = items;
                    results.count = items.size();
                } else {
                    List<Item> filtered_items = new ArrayList<Item>();
                    if(deleted)
                        items = all_items;
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                        String modifiedName = items.get(i).getRealName().toLowerCase();
                        String modifiedQuery = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
                        modifiedName = encode_lithuanian(modifiedName);
                        modifiedQuery = encode_lithuanian(modifiedQuery);
                        if (modifiedName.contains(modifiedQuery))
                            filtered_items.add(items.get(i));
                    }
                    results.values = filtered_items;
                    results.count = filtered_items.size();
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                items = (List<Item>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public int show_size(){
                return items.size();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create adapter for different list views.
Then in the edittext aftertextchange listener apply the text filter for all the adapters. Have a look at:

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-search-listview-using-filter/

```
adapter1 = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist1);
list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
adapter2 = new ListViewAdapter(this, arraylist2);
list2.setAdapter(adapter2);    

editsearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
    //TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String text = editsearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    adapter1.filter(text);
    adapter2.filter(text);
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Riasat's answer inspired me and I think it could be possible to do it without any code repetition: of course for each list view, you'd have a adapter with will be more or less the same. But it could be great to create a notifier, which will say to all the adapter to refresh. Something like:

An interface to go a bit further as your only requirements:

```
/**
* Created by laurentmeyer on 03/03/15.
*/
public interface RefreshInterface {
     void refresh();
     void searchForText(String searchedText);
     void searchWithSomethingElse(Object SomethingElse);
}
```

Then modify a bit the adapter:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;

/**
 * Created by laurentmeyer on 03/03/15.
 */
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements RefreshInterface{
    private Context context;
    private List<Item> items;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Context context, List<Item> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView image = (NetworkImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView type = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        Item i = items.get(position);

        image.setImageUrl(i.getIcon(), imageLoader);
        if(items.get(0).getName().contains("taksi"))
            image.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.telefonas);
        else
            image.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.be_fono);
        name.setText(i.getRealName());
        type.setText(i.getType());
        return convertView;
    }

    public List<Item> getItems(){
        return items;
    }

    public Filter getFilter(final List<Item> all_items, final boolean deleted) {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
                    results.values = items;
                    results.count = items.size();
                } else {
                    List<Item> filtered_items = new ArrayList<Item>();
                    if(deleted)
                        items = all_items;
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                        String modifiedName = items.get(i).getRealName().toLowerCase();
                        String modifiedQuery = charSequence.toString().toLowerCase();
                        modifiedName = encode_lithuanian(modifiedName);
                        modifiedQuery = encode_lithuanian(modifiedQuery);
                        if (modifiedName.contains(modifiedQuery))
                            filtered_items.add(items.get(i));
                    }
                    results.values = filtered_items;
                    results.count = filtered_items.size();
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                items = (List<Item>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            public int show_size(){
                return items.size();
            }
        };
    }

    // What you'll do when you'll want to refresh (why not?)
    @Override
    public void refresh() {

    }

    // What you'll do when you'll want to search from SearchView
    @Override
    public void searchForText(String searchedText) {
    }

    // What you'll do when you'll want to have a look with another cool Object like a LatLong or some other stuff (optional, of course)
    @Override
    public void searchWithSomethingElse(Object SomethingElse) {

    }
}
```

And then your Fragment will also change a bit but not as much as in the other solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by laurentmeyer on 03/03/15.
 */
public class AllLists extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;
    private Context context = null;
    private int position = 0;
    private String location;
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private List<Item> tmp_items = new ArrayList<Item>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private String tmp_s = "";
    private static Locale myLocale;
    private EasyTracker easyTracker = null;
    private RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    /*
    Here is a modification
     */
    // Create a ArrayList containing all the adapters (which are directly connected to the listViews)
    // which will need to be refreshed by the search view. I made it static because maybe you can use
    // it in other instances and it could be easier.
    public static ArrayList<RefreshInterface> toBeRefreshed;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alllists, container, false);
        View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.small_icon);
        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        relativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        setLanguage();
        navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);
        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        position = bundle.getInt("position");
        location = bundle.getString("location");
        image.setImageDrawable(navMenuIcons.getDrawable(position));
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        easyTracker = EasyTracker.getInstance(context);
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
        items = db.getAllItems(location);
        tmp_items = db.getAllItems(location);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, items);
        /*
        Here is a modification
         */
        toBeRefreshed.add(adapter);
        listView.addHeaderView(header, "", false);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int list_position, long id) {
                easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("List",
                        location, adapter.getItems().get(list_position - 1).getName(), null).build());
                if (location.equals("accommodation") || location.equals("eat") || location.equals("events")
                        || location.equals("entertainment") || location.equals("places") || location.equals("cinema")) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(context, ItemScreen.class);
                    i.putExtra("position", list_position - 1);
                    i.putExtra("location", location);
                    i.putExtra("name", adapter.getItems().get(list_position - 1).getRealName());
                    startActivity(i);
                } else if (location.equals("taxi")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + adapter.getItems().get(list_position - 1).getType()));
                    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
                    List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
                    if (infos.size() > 0)
                        startActivity(intent);
                    else
                        Toast.makeText(context, R.string.cant_handle, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                easyTracker.send(MapBuilder.createEvent("Search",
                        "search", s, null).build());
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
                    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(context, tmp_items);
                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
                if (tmp_s.length() > s.length()) {
                    /*
                    Here call the logic you implemented in your adapter functions like:
                    for (RefreshInterface r : toBeRefreshed){
                        r.filter(String)
                    }
                     */
                } else {
                   /*
                   Same as above
                    */
                }
                tmp_s = s;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
        mSearchView.setQuery("", false);
    }
}
```